# Visual Studio Code keeps running

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

i'm trying to use visual studio code to run various c programs but the code never outputs as it stays in a perpetual state of running.

Here's an example of the code i'm trying to run

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct comp
 {
   float real;
   float imag;
 } complex;

complex mult(complex a,complex b)
{
 complex c;
 c.real=a.real*b.real - a.imag*b.imag;
 c.imag=a.real*b.imag + a.imag*b.real;
 return c;
}

int main()
{

  float re,im;
  complex a,b;
    
   printf("Please enter the first complex number (re, im): ");
   scanf("%f%f", &re, &im);
   
   a.real = re; a.imag = im;

   printf("Please enter the second complex number (re, im): ");
   scanf("%f%f", &re, &im); 

   b.real = re; b.imag = im;

   a = mult(a,b);

   printf("Their product is %f + %fi \n", a.real, a.imag);
   return 0;
}
```

[And here is a screenshot of the application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xcn3P.png)

As I said when I run the code it just get's stuck "running".

I've downloaded the necessary extensions for visual studio code that let you run C/C++.

Anyone encountered this problem before?

Thanks

Comment: That's because you have to run it through the terminal. It's the output window, not the input window.

Comment: How do you run the code? In the screenshot it looks as if the code isn't even running. Have you tried clicking on the triangle "play" button in the top right?

Comment: read the C++ pages in the VSC doc

Answer (score 1):

You need to correctly configure your Code Runner extension from the generated JSON config under `.vscode` folder in your workspace. Also, you might haven't focused you've opened **GitHub Authentication** output log, not the code runner's if it actually ran successfully, which doesn't seem:

[image: GitHub Auth SS]

If you find it hard to configure, then switch to the Terminal section and type the following command to compile and execute it manually:

```
gcc -Wall -o main main.c;  ./main    # for PowerShell
gcc -Wall -o main main.c && main     # for Command Prompt
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem. Follow the below steps and I hope it will work for you too.

1. CTRL+SHIFT+X
2. Type in search box Code Runner
3. Install the extension
4. Then click on File - Preferences - Settings
5. Type code run in the search box.
6. Scroll down until you find Code-runner: Run In Terminal. Check the box Whether to
   run code in Integrated Terminal.
7. Restart VS Code